# Uniquely identify which instance of a website is active or triggers an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a web based contact center application that has when a user has multiple contacts/pages open and attempts to submit data it is sometimes writes the wrong data to the db.
Is there a way to uniquely identify which one of the same page is triggering the event so that it stores the data correctly?

Comment: Why don't you create a unique key on the client-side and include this key in each request?
This key you can show on UI, and include in the request.

Comment: can you share an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique key on client-side:

```
function uuidv4() {
 return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
  var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
  return v.toString(16);
 });
}
```

and then send it to the server.

In this case on UI you will see a unique key of every page, and on server you will know from which page was sended request.

https://jsfiddle.net/sergeymnet/5p62q1md/43/